# Error when trying to migrate old app engine projects into a new organization on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

We have several older projects (2-3 years old) written with App Engine in our Google Apps domain. We now are trying to "migrate" these to be listed under our organization in the GCP console. The error is "you do not have sufficient permissions to view this page" after I click "Migrate". However, I am a domain admin and have full access to the projects. Anyone know the trick?

Comment: By full access, do you mean you are listed as Editor or Owner on the projects you are trying to migrate?

Comment: Thanks, @Adam. Turns out that I did not have full access to the project BILLING so that prevented me from moving them to my ORG which had a different billing account. After the right permissions were in place (had to get the developer to do it), the projects transferred. Thanks for your response, tho!

Comment: I can see you have resolved this issue. Consider posting self-answer which will help other users looking at this thread.

Answer (score 1):

The developer of the project needed to give me not only "Project Owner" permissions, but ALSO "Billing Administrator" permissions to the individual projects. Once I had these permissions I could transfer the projects to the compnay ORG billing account.